# Searching for a "Dependencies spy tool"

Tags: c#-4.0, installation, copy, dependencies

My problem: I have 2 pcs. On the first I installed an `C#, .Net4.0 desktop application`.

Is it possible to run the same application on pc2 - without having the installation file? Just copy the target folder (incl. .exe, .dlls, etc.) from pc1 without having the installation file isn't enough.

So, could please somebody suggest a good tool, that finds all depended files to build let's say an transportable zip?

Thanks in advance.
Silva

Comment: Why can't you just run the installer again on the second PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ILSpy http://ilspy.net/ and Checkasm http://www.amberfish.net/ are both pretty good at this.